# Get user input and display mm/dd/year the user has been alive

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS Dev and learning user input/output. I am not able to figure out how to show the correct output for mm/dd/yyyy when the user is asked to enter date of birth to find out how long the user has been alive.

```
NSDate *actualDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

double getDays = [self.dayTextField.text doubleValue];
double getMonths = [self.monthTextField.text doubleValue];
double getYears = [self.yearTextField.text doubleValue];

NSCalendar *g = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *dateOfBirth = [g dateFromComponents:comps];

double secondsSinceEarlierDate = [actualDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateOfBirth];

double minutes = secondsSinceEarlierDate/60;
double hours = minutes/60;
double weeks = days/7;

//Can not figure out these...
double days = hours/24;
double months = weeks * 0.229984378;
double years = months/12; 

self.showMonthsLabel.text = [@(months) stringValye];
self.showDaysLabel.text = [@(days) stringValye];
self.showYearsLabel.text = [@(years) stringValye];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int day = [self.dayTextField.text intValue];
int month = [self.monthTextField.text intValue];
int year = [self.yearTextField.text intValue];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *birthDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[birthDateComponents setDay:day];
[birthDateComponents setMonth:month];
[birthDateComponents setYear:year];
NSDate *birthDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:birthDateComponents];
NSDateComponents *intervalComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:birthDate
                                                     toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                    options:0];
NSLog(@"Alive for: %li days, %li months, %li years", (long)intervalComponents.day, (long)intervalComponents.month, (long)intervalComponents.year);
```

Outputs:

```
Alive for: XX days, XX months, XX years
```

Comment: Is there a way, I can show milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, weeks the user is alive for? I did try this---- [birthDateComponents setWeek: [birthDateComponents week];. It shows me 0 output...